# What's the alternative for ResponseType in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, httpresponse, angular5

I am trying to rewrite a wrapper for http requests using generics. Before Angular 5 there is `Observable<responseType>` is available. I am looking for alternative for generic responseType. My code is as follows.

```
request(endpoint: string, options?: RequestOptions, apiOptions?: IApiServiceOptions): Observable<any> {
        options = options || {method: 'GET'};
        apiOptions = apiOptions || {};

        // build url
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}${endpoint}`;
        this.log.debugApiCall(url, this.source, options);

        // set headers
        const authToken = this.authStorage.getAuthenticationToken(this.service);

        let headers = new HttpHeaders();

        if (authToken) {
          headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken.jwtToken}`);
        }
        headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        options.headers = headers;

        // make request and handle errors
        return this
          .http
          .request(options.method, url, options)
          .do((req) => {
            this.log.debugApiResponse(url, this.source, req);
          })
          .catch((res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            switch (res.status) {
              case 0:
                this.log.error(res, `>>server down<<: ${res} - if the server is up, make sure this isn't a CORS error`);
                this._serverDown$.next();
                return Observable.throw(res);
              case 401:
                this.log.debug(`authentication error: ${res}`);

                if (!apiOptions.disableServerDown) {
                  this._authError$.next(authToken);
                } else {
                  this.log.debug('authError$ not emitted since apiOptions.disableServerDown === true');
                }

                return Observable.throw(res);
              default:
                this.log.error(res, 'Unexpected Error');
                return Observable.throw(res);
            }
          });
      }

      get(url: string, options?: RequestOptions, apiOptions?: IApiServiceOptions): Observable<any> {
        options = options || {};
        options.method = 'GET';

        return this.request(url, options, apiOptions);
      }

      post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptions, apiOptions?: IApiServiceOptions): Observable<any> {
        options = options || {};
        options.method = 'POST';
        options.body = body;

        return this.request(url, options, apiOptions);
      }

      put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptions, apiOptions?: IApiServiceOptions): Observable<any> {
        options = options || {};
        options.method = 'PUT';
        options.body = body;

        return this.request(url, options, apiOptions);
      }
```

However, the return type of request method is `Observable<HttpResponse<T>>`. What should be the value of T in general ? I ended up with any as of now. 
Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this.

```
export type ResponseData = ArrayBuffer | Blob | string;

export type RequestResponse = Observable<ResponseData | Object | any
  | HttpEvent<ResponseData | any>
  | HttpResponse<ResponseData | Object>>;

 request(endpoint: string, options?: IRequestOptions, apiOptions?: IApiServiceOptions): Observable<RequestResponse> {
............
```

Comment: This one helped me to fix.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Angular HTTP client documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response) and [Typescript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), you can use generic type in between of function name and its arguments in http requests. E.g. taking your `get` function as example, your code would look like this

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: RequestOptions, apiOptions?: IApiServiceOptions): Observable<T> {
    options = options || {};
    options.method = 'GET';

    return this.request<T>(url, options, apiOptions);
}
```

Notice where generic type `<T>` was added. Then you can simply call your function via next line

```
someHttpServiceInstance.get<SomeClass>(...some arguments).subscribe(
    (output: SomeClass) => { ... }
);
```

[Proof of concept](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-mc1spn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This looks convincing. I will test and get back. Thanks a lot @vagrantAI

Answer (score 0):

Although [`HttpClient` documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) doesn't reflect that and uses `any`, `request` and other methods are [already typed](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.4/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L76-L300) and allow for generic types. Method signatures depend on `responseType` and `observe` options as it would be expected, because the result depends on them.